# Generate many to many in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, many-to-many, poco

I have generated an edm file that looks like the following:

[image]

How do I convert this to a many to many edm? I'll be using POCO, so I want it to look something like:

```
public class User{
    public List<Role> Roles {get; set;}
    /* Other prop here */
}

public class Role{
    public List<User> Users {get; set;}
    /* Other prop here */
}
```

Using EF4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well something you may/may not know - if you remove that **UserRoleId** field from the *UserRole* table, EF will not need to map that join table at all, and it will create the many-to-many assocation for you, and do a "silent-join" behind the scenes to the join table.

That being said, if you **must** have that extra field, then you could do something like this:

```
var userWithRoles = ctx.Users.Include("UserRoles.Role");
```

And likewise:

```
var roleWithUsers = ctx.Roles.Include("UserRoles.User");
```

As i said though, in most cases of a many-to-many, only the FK's are required in the join table.

If possible, remove that field, then update your model and the many-to-many will "just work".

Comment: You're like a super hero when it comes to EF.

Comment: Hahah, thanks for the compliment. :) It's just that i'm doing lots of EF4 at the moment, so most of the questions here about it i have already come across and solved. I used to answer lots of questions on ASP.NET Web Forms, but now that ASP.NET MVC is out, i don't care about Web Forms anymore. :)